# Upload IMG in PHP doing nothing

Tags: php, html, image, upload

I'm trying to upload an image, but I don't even get the "hi" message returned inside my span...Here's the HTML:

```html
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form_c">
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title"/>
        <label for="content">Content:</label>
            <textarea name="content" id="content"></textarea>
        <label for="date">Release Date (RRRR-MM-DD):</label>
            <input type="text" name="date" id="date"/>
        <label for="price">Price:</label>
            <input type="text" name="price" id="price"/>
        <label for="album_img">Price:</label>
            <input type="file" name="album_img" id="album_img"/>
            <span>
                <?php     
                    if (isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {
                        require_once "/../../controllers/admin/File_Handler.php";
                        $file_handle = new File_Handler;
                        $file_handle->uploadImg();
                    }
                ?>
            </span>
        <button type="submit" name="btn_submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Here's the PHP:

```html
<?php

Class File_Handler {
    
private $file_temp;
private $file_name;
private $file_size;
private $file_type; 
// Max size 2mb
private $max_size = 2000000;
private $target_path = "../../images/";
    
    public function __construct () {
        
        $this->file_temp = $_FILES['album_img']['tmp_name']; 
        $this->file_name = $_FILES['album_img']['name']; 
        $this->file_size = $_FILES['album_img']['size']; 
        $this->file_type = $_FILES['album_img']['type']; 
        $this->target_path += $this->file_name;
        
    }
    
    public function setMaxSize ($size) {
        
        $this->max_size = size;
           
    }
    
    public function uploadImg () {
        
        return "hi";
        
        if ($this->file_size > $this->max_size) {
            return "file size too big";      
        }
         
        else if (move_uploaded_file($this->file_temp, $this->target_path)) {
            return "The image ".  $this->file_name . " has been uploaded successfully!"; 
        } 
        else {
            return "There was an error uploading the image, please try again!";
        }
      
    }
    
}
```

I'm thinking the php isn't even going off, because all it seems to be doing is refreshing the page. It's probably something silly, but I can't figure it out!

Comment: `return` returns what you specified and **exits** the function/method. If you want to print something, use `echo`.

Comment: More about `return` here http://php.net/return

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Hey, thanks, that solved my issue of getting no feedback. Okay, so it is giving me the success message, but I do not actually see the image in my images folder.

Comment: Make sure the permissions for `../../images` (so 2 directories up and then the images folder) are properly set.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois talked it over with my dad...actually the issue was in this line in my constructor "$this->target_path += $this->file_name;" . I changed it to " $this->target_path = "../../images/" . $_FILES['album_img']['name'];" and it works. I guess += doesn't work in php, or in this case?

Comment: `+=` is for addition (math). Use `.=` for concating.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I knew it was something silly, thanks!